# Guide users who try to use the tag [mac]

Tags: discussion, tags

I see some users who use the [mac](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) tag when they really need to talk about [osx](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx).

As this is a **Software** Recommendations site, I doubt there will be many (if any at all) questions that will be on-topic talking about [mac](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) *hardware*.

So I propose we show users who try to use the [mac](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) tag the following message:

`The tag [mac] refers to the hardware of an Apple computer. This is a software recommendations site, so if you are looking for a recommendation on OSX software (the OS that runs on Mac's, please use the [tag:osx] tag.`

Unless I'm mistaken and there genuinely are questions that would be on topic on this site about the mac hardware.

Comment: One possible route I'm seeing is: if there are *no* (or extreeeemely few) legit questions about Mac hardware, we synonymize [mac] to [osx], and let the legit hardware questions (if there are any) make their own tag ([mac-hardware]?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several sites ([su], [apple.se], [ubuntu.se], [sf]) have `mac` as a tag meaning Mac hardware and in practice implying OSX as far as we're concerned. So having [mac](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) as a synonym will help for incoming migrations: if we create the synonym, incoming migrations tagged `mac` on the source site will get tagged [osx](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) here. I've approved the synonym.

Answer (score 3):

As per Undo's comment and looking at nobody denying the proposal, I've gone ahead and suggested a synonym for [osx](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) over [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/osx/synonyms).

If you agree to @Undo, please upvote the suggestion.